# Use Koloda library with Parse data source

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, swipe

I'm using Koloda library (https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda) to display data in swipe views Tinder like cards.

```
import UIKit
import Koloda
import pop
import Parse
import Bolts
import ParseUI

private var numberOfCards: UInt = 5


class ViewController: UIViewController, KolodaViewDataSource,     KolodaViewDelegate {

    var ids : [String] = []

    @IBOutlet weak var kolodaView: KolodaView!
    @IBAction func undo(sender: AnyObject) {
        kolodaView?.revertAction()

    }

    @IBAction func left(sender: AnyObject) {
        kolodaView?.swipe(SwipeResultDirection.Left)

    }

    @IBAction func right(sender: AnyObject) {
        kolodaView?.swipe(SwipeResultDirection.Right)

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        kolodaView.dataSource = self
        kolodaView.delegate = self

        self.modalTransitionStyle =  UIModalTransitionStyle.FlipHorizontal
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: KolodaViewDataSource


    func kolodaNumberOfCards(koloda: KolodaView) -> UInt {
        return numberOfCards
    }

    func kolodaViewForCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) ->  UIView {
        return UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "Card_like_\(index + 1)"))

    }

    func kolodaViewForCardOverlayAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) -> OverlayView? {
        return NSBundle.mainBundle().loadNibNamed("OverlayView",
            owner: self, options: nil)[0] as? OverlayView
    }

    //MARK: KolodaViewDelegate

    func kolodaDidSwipedCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt,  direction: SwipeResultDirection) {
        //Example: loading more cards
        if index >= 3 {
            numberOfCards = 6
            kolodaView.reloadData()
        }
    }

    func kolodaDidRunOutOfCards(koloda: KolodaView) {
        //Example: reloading
        kolodaView.resetCurrentCardNumber()
    }

    func kolodaDidSelectCardAtIndex(koloda: KolodaView, index: UInt) {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "http://yalantis.com/")!)
    }

    func kolodaShouldApplyAppearAnimation(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func kolodaShouldMoveBackgroundCard(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func kolodaShouldTransparentizeNextCard(koloda: KolodaView) -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    func kolodaBackgroundCardAnimation(koloda: KolodaView) -> POPPropertyAnimation? {
        return nil
    }
}
```

The above code works fine with the six images I have stored in Assets. What I want is to fill every card with data from a ParseUser (Text and a image). I've been thinking about something similar of filling a tableView with ParseData but I can't find the correct solution. This is the purpose of KolodaView:

> KolodaView is a class designed to simplify the implementation of Tinder like cards on iOS. It adds convenient functionality such as a UITableView-style dataSource/delegate interface for loading views dynamically, and efficient view loading, unloading .

Maybe there is another library to do the same.

Answer (score 4):

You can use Koloda in the same way as UITableView. Start fetching objects in viewDidLoad asynchronously and then call reloadData in callback, so Koloda has to reconfigure its views.

Note: There is networking_example in repository https://github.com/Yalantis/Koloda/tree/networking_example